# Why is flex display not working directly on inner div in Tailwind CSS V3.2.2?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

So I have been trying to use Flex display in tailwind css following a tutorial to build a portfolio. Now the person instructing is able to use flex directly on inner div component and is able to use "Justify-center; Items-center" property. When I tried in my project, I was not able to do so until and unless I introduce Flex in parent Div. Why is this happening. I tried finding solution in Tailwind CSS documentation but failed so.
Another problem I am facing is in the child Div component. I am trying to use a breakpoint such that it shows flex direction column wise for device size lower than md(i.e. 768px), but the breakpoint is not working and whatever I write unprefixed is applied. I have used the same breakpoint property in using mobile view hamburger menu. There I just used `<ul className='hidden md:flex'>` and it worked.
Now I have used Tailwind CSS in my earlier 2-3 projects but after the update I guess, I am not able to use it that smoothly. Can anyone please help.

```
<div name="home" className='flex h-screen w-full bg-gradient-to-b from-black to-gray-800'>
        <div className='max-w-screen-lg mx-auto flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center justify-center'>
            <div>
                <h2>I'm a Full Stack Developer</h2>
                <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ut tristique libero. Pellentesque sed blandit metus. Duis et tortor vel mauris congue vestibulum. Cras ultricies sodales diam, eu mattis tortor faucibus sit amet. Maecenas sed mattis diam. Donec diam nisi, posuere a pellentesque sed, vestibulum vel ipsum. Sed ut fringilla.
                </p>
                <div >
                    <button>
                        Portfolio 
                        <span><HiArrowNarrowRight /></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div><h1 className='text-white'>Hello World</h1></div>  /*just for debugging else I will be using image here*/ 
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried using Flex properties which i have used in inner div to parent div, but I was not able to find the solution. Then I tried degrading my tailwind version but then also it was not working. I tried using grid in tailwind css but the design I have in my mind gets complicated. I have to use flex only with breakpoints

Comment: "Now the person instructing is able to use flex directly on inner div component and is able to use `Justify-center; Items-center` property. When I tried in my project, I was not able to do so until and unless I introduce Flex in parent Div". Surely you are able to just by writing in the class names? Perhaps you mean didn't give you the desired effects? Your code seems to work as expected [in Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/sDoK9vz8u9) so it seems like some misconfiguration. Perhaps check that the `content` file globs sufficiently cover the file that the code is in.

Comment: Can you guide me on how to check that the `content` file globs sufficiently cover the file that the code is in?

Comment: Look at the `content` file globs and then review if the location of the file is sufficiently covered by the file globs.